# Security scan output

Tags: security

I am looking for help with "Confidence" in WPScan. What does it mean? There's nothing in the docs.

[WPScan](https://wpscan.org)

[+] http://derpnstink.local/weblog/readme.html
 | Found By: Direct Access (Aggressive Detection)
 | **Confidence**: 100%

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not related to programming and it might rather belong on [wordpress.stackexchange.com](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1):

WPScan used brute-forcing in order to detect sensitive information on your website. It detected the "readme.html" file and it asks you to check if it is anything sensitive in the file, that may help the attacker.

If the file is empty, there is nothing to worry about.

The readme file is useful for an attacker because he can find out which version of WP are you using, which theme, which plugins etc.

Comment: Thanks. So if wpscan outputs Confidence: 60%, is it telling me that the "hacker" has a 60% chance of gaining access? Is 60% more vulnerable than say, 100%?

Comment: No, confidence means that WPScanner is 100% sure that readme.html exists.